# How to add a <caption> tag in ng-grid table?

Tags: html, css, ng-grid

I need to display a table via ng-grid, but the table has a <caption> tag. See the yellow section in the image below. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-grid uses `divs`, not `tables`. You can use a custom `headerRowTemplate` to achieve a similar result, however.

The default header row template is here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/src/templates/headerRowTemplate.html

You can create your own and add a row on top, then reference it with the `headerRowTemplate` option in your grid options:

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myHeaderTemplate">
  <div>
    <div class="headerTop ngHeaderCell">
      <span class="content">Submissions</span>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 30px; top: 30px; position: absolute">
      <div ng-style="{ height: col.headerRowHeight }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngHeaderCell">
        <div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: col.headerRowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">&nbsp;</div>
        <div ng-header-cell></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Make sure that the header container is sized to hold both the column headers and your caption:

```css
.ngHeaderContainer, .ngHeaderScroller {
  height: 60px !important;
}
```

And add styles for the caption:

```css
.headerTop {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  padding: 0px 0 0 6px;
}

.headerTop .content {
  padding: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Here's a demonstration plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fT1IrO?p=preview